# groupBy on snd element of tuple

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

So I would like to use `groupBy` to group my list of tuples based on their `snd` element. Every tuple with the same `snd` element should be in the same list

```
group ::  [(Int,Int)] -> [[(Int,Int)]]
group = groupBy (\a b -> snd a == snd b) lijst
```

A `groupBy` of the list `[(1,2),(8,9),(5,2),(9,2),(3,9),(1,1)]` should return
`[[(1,2),(5,2),(9,2)],[(8,9),(3,9)],[1,1]]`.

However it returns  `[[(1,2)],[(8,9)],[(5,2),(9,2)],[(3,9)],[(1,1)]]`.

How can I make this function work ?

Comment: You first "order" by the second tuple. Note that `groupBy` is an "online" algorithm, it only groups "sequences" that satisfy the predicate, it does not look in the "far future" to see if some other element eventually shows up with the same `snd` item.

Comment: If you want this result you need to sort the list. groupBy only merges adjacent elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading in the documentation of [groupBy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:groupBy) we are referred to the documentation of [group](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:group), which states

> The group function takes a list and returns a list of lists such that
>   the concatenation of the result is equal to the argument.

That's a not very obvious way of saying: "We only group equal, adjacent elements."

So [sortBy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortBy) your list first.